# Cannot add field...row size...greater than maximum allowed size

Tags: mysql, innodb, temp-tables

I'm seeing the following error in my MySQL logs:

`` [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot add field `wd_field_ft_95_240` in table `tmp`.`#sql_1_0` because after adding it, the row size is 8155 which is greater than maximum allowed size (8126) for a record on index leaf page. ``

Is this `tmp` database some kind of internal MySQL structure? Is this something I need to care about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some MySQL queries create [internal temporary tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) to hold partial results.

As of MySQL 5.7.6, the default storage engine for internal temporary tables is InnoDB, which has a pretty small limit on row size, as you can see (though BLOB/TEXT columns can go beyond that limit).

You can go back to the old pre-5.7 default storage engine for internal temporary tables:

```
 internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine=MyISAM
```

This is the workaround mentioned in this bug: "[Bug #77398 row size too large in mysql 5.7 query](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77398)"

Comment: Is this just a [Warning]? Does it cause the query to fail? or does it just prevent it from running the query with the best optimisations? I'm seeing these entries in my error logs, but it doesn't say that the query also failed.

Comment: I believe it causes the query to fail. The client who ran the query gets an error. I'm not sure why the server logs it as a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I'll bet you have lots of columns declared `VARCHAR(255)`.  I'll also bet that most of those columns will never need 255 characters.  Shrink them.

If that does not suffice, change a *few* to be `TEXT`; the data will be stored off-page and not impact the 8K limit as badly.

If that does not suffice, we can talk about "vertical partitioning".  At that point, please show us the query that precipitated the error.  If you are doing `SELECT *`, change it to specify only the columns you really need.

Do not use MyISAM, that is a step backward.  And it is going away in the next version, so a future migration will be hurt.

Comment: Do you have a say in the development of MySQL? I'm trying to migrate a database from 5.5 to 5.7 and it's a nightmare. New and better is great, but dropping backwards compatibility makes adoption more difficult.

Comment: @AuntJemima - Ms Pancakes, I do not have a _direct_ say in the development.  A further note here is that 8.0 has further changed the handling of temp tables; I do not know if it fixes your problem.  Meanwhile, Bill's suggestion is simple (a one-time fix to my.cnf, plus restart), and I expect it to work.