# How to read a mysql error log

Tags: mysql

I keep getting the following error in mysql error log.

```
2018-05-16T05:00:09.031837Z 624962 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot add field `jobcontrac14__REPLACEMENT_PERIOD_319` in table `tmp`.`#sql_4c85_0` because after adding it, the row size is 8134 which is greater than maximum allowed size (8126) for a record on index leaf page.
```

Below are the create table log, and data length in REPLACEMENT_PERIOD column.

The data length in this column is max 8.

Q) Why do I still get the above error log about row size being greater than max allowed?

Q) From `jobcontrac14__REPLACEMENT_PERIOD_319`, can I know which row it is talking about? The text `_14`, `_319` and `tmp`.`#sql_4c85_0` remain the same in ALL the logs.

Q) How can I know which query is causing this error?

Q) Please point me to any documentation on how to read/understand mysql error logs.

```
| JOB_CONTRACTS | CREATE TABLE `JOB_CONTRACTS` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `REPLACEMENT_PERIOD` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FEE_STRUCTURE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POTENTIAL_BILLING` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INVOICE_AFTER_DAYS` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OFFERED_COMPENSATION` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLAT_FEE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_JOB_ID_CONTRACTS_indx` (`JOB_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_ID_CONTRACT_1` FOREIGN KEY (`JOB_ID`) REFERENCES `JOBS` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4871 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |




mysql> SELECT COUNT(*), REPLACEMENT_PERIOD, LENGTH(REPLACEMENT_PERIOD) FROM JOB_CONTRACTS GROUP BY REPLACEMENT_PERIOD;
+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| COUNT(*) | REPLACEMENT_PERIOD | LENGTH(REPLACEMENT_PERIOD) |
+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
|        2 | 0                  |                          1 |
|        2 | 1 year             |                          6 |
|      249 | 120                |                          3 |
|        5 | 120 days           |                          8 |
|       13 | 15                 |                          2 |
|       87 | 180                |                          3 |
|       28 | 180 days           |                          8 |
|      127 | 30                 |                          2 |
|       24 | 30 days            |                          7 |
|      155 | 45                 |                          2 |
|      815 | 60                 |                          2 |
|       33 | 60 days            |                          7 |
|        5 | 75                 |                          2 |
|     2483 | 90                 |                          2 |
|      770 | 90 days            |                          7 |
|        2 | None               |                          4 |
|        3 | Other              |                          5 |
+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. That would be a single SQL file setting up the table, adding data and making the failing query.

Comment: If you are doing SELECT *    then give the columns that you really need of.

Answer (score 0):

Please see 
[Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053663/cannot-add-field-row-size-greater-than-maximum-allowed-size)

You need to switch to `MyISAM` engine for temp tables (which in your case are created during `group by` execution)
Add this line to `my.cnf`

```
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine=MyISAM
```