# Google MySQL cloud database flag is not exist: internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mysql-error-1064

We have google cloud MySQL Instance and we are getting error like:

```
InnoDB: Cannot add field CE_Lead__c in table client_1067.#sql-ib1179556-1243586840 because after adding it, the row size is 8148 which is greater than maximum allowed size (8126) for a record on index leaf page.
```

The workaround to fix this issue is to set internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine=MYISAM

I can't see this flag in Database flags section, also as per the google documents this variable is not exist in google cloud, however I can see it exist in MySQL 5.7

**Database flag not exist in google cloud supported flag:**

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags-mysql

**Database flag exist in MySQL 5.7**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine

Thanks
SKS

Answer (score 0):

Some flags are not supported in Cloud SQL MySQL due to the managed nature of the service (stability/streamline reasons, etc.) You could try other workarounds like decreasing the memory usage mentioned further below on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053663/cannot-add-field-row-size-greater-than-maximum-allowed-size), if you decide you need to use flags that are not supported on Cloud SQL you can choose to create your own self managed MySQL instance in order to bypass the Cloud SQL limitations. (for example using [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql))

Comment: Thanks @Andres, Can you please suggest me which memory settings I need to decrease, also is there any other way to fix this issue in the existing Cloud SQL MySQL server.

Comment: For the memory usage decrease it depends on what you are trying to do in the particular query or SHOW CREATE TABLE, you can refer to Rick James answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053663/cannot-add-field-row-size-greater-than-maximum-allowed-size), I am not aware of other way to fix this